# Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Templates

Tags: symfony

Replacement of the template of the FOS does not work well.
Cause I'm having problems you do not know. It can be seen better, please tell me.

MyBundle.php

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle {

    public function getParent() {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    } 
}
```

MyBundle\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
{% endif %}

{% block title %}Demo Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}


{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

vendor \ friendsofsymfony \ user-bundle \ FOS \ UserBundle contents of the \ Resources \ views \ Security of login.html.twig are displayed.

Answer (score 9):

Put your file in app directory

```
app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig
```

And clear cache.

Comment: omg, clear cache   **sudo php bin/console cache:clear**   worked for me !

Comment: @VladimirCh, you shouldn't use sudo to clear cache, instead you should [modify your permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/file_permissions.html) and execute it with normal user.

Comment: 1st of all - thx for link, aded 2 fav. and 2nd,  time-by-time worked on many platforms, many users.... thats why i uses sudo, for lil dirty and fast help.